# Calculating impulse to frame from a flywheel and piston system

Tags: classical-mechanics, energy-conservation

My question is related to a previous question, presented in [342655](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/342655/).  I am taking the same scenario to ask a different question:  In a flywheel and piston inertial system, how do you calculate the forces transmitted to the frame supporting the flywheel shaft?

Scenario:
"Imagine a piston in a cylinder, lying down so that the piston moves horizontally. The cylinder is open at both ends (no compression of a gas). For simplicity, lets assume no friction, no sound, no heat effects, no gravity, and that the system is isolated in a vacuum.

The piston has a connecting rod attached to a revolving flywheel. Consequently the piston oscillates back and forth within the cylinder. The motion of the piston resembles simple harmonic motion ; its kinetic energy oscillates across time, between a maximum at the middle of the cylinder, to zero at either end of the cylinder.

For simple harmonic motion (e.g., a weight attached to a spring, and oscillating horizontally on a frictionless table top), it is well known that oscillation of kinetic energy of the weight is counterbalanced exactly by a coincident oscillation of potential energy (e.g., potential energy due to compression of a spring) in such a way that the total energy remains constant at all times:

\begin{align}
& K = E \sin^2(wt) \\
& P = E \cos^2(wt) \\
& K + P = E
\end{align}

Furthermore, such motion is indefinite (excluding friction, etc...)."

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Kinematic

\begin{align*}
&x=\cos \left( \varphi  \right) r_{{1}}+r_{{2}}\cos \left( \psi
 \right)\\
&r_1\,\sin(\varphi)=r_2\,\sin(\psi)
\end{align*}

from here you obtain

\begin{align*}
 &x(\varphi)=\cos \left( \varphi  \right) r_{{1}}+r_{{2}}\sqrt {1-{\frac {
 \left( \sin \left( \varphi  \right)  \right) ^{2}{r_{{1}}}^{2}}{{r_
{{2}}}^{2}}}}
\end{align*}

The kinetic Energy is:

\begin{align*}
 &T=\frac{m}{2}\left(\frac{\partial x(\varphi)}{\partial\varphi}\,\dot{\varphi}\right)^2+\frac{M\,r_1^2}{2}\,
 \dot{\varphi}^2:=\frac{1}{2}\,g(\varphi)\dot{\varphi}^2
\end{align*}

and with Euler- Lagrange you obtain the equation of motion
\begin{align*}
 &\ddot \varphi +\frac 12\,{\frac { \left( {\frac {d}{d\varphi }}g \left(
\varphi  \right)  \right) {\dot\varphi }^{2}}{g \left( \varphi  \right) }
}=0
\end{align*}
To obtain the constraint force of the rod $~r_1$, you "open a gap" $~q_n~$ towards $~r_1$ thus
Kinematic
\begin{align*}
&x=\cos \left( \varphi  \right) (r_{{1}}+q_n)+r_{{2}}\cos \left( \psi
 \right)\\
&(r_1+q_n)\,\sin(\varphi)=r_2\,\sin(\psi)
\end{align*}
From here you obtain $~x(\varphi~,q_n)$
you have now two generalized coordinates $~\varphi~,q_n$
The kinetic energy is

\begin{align*}
 &T=\frac{m}{2}\,v^2+\frac{M\,r_1^2}{2}\,\dot{\varphi}^2\\
 &\text{with}\\
 &v=\frac{\partial x}{\partial \varphi}\,\dot{\varphi}+
 \frac{\partial x}{\partial q_n}\,\dot{q}_n\\\\
 \Rightarrow\\
 &T:=\frac{1}{2}\,g(\varphi~,q_n)\dot{\varphi}^2+
 h(\varphi~,q_n)\,\dot{\varphi}\,\dot{q}_n+\frac{1}{2}\,f(\varphi~,q_n)\,
 \dot{q}_n^2
\end{align*}

you have to use now Euler- Language with holonomic constraint equation (you "close the gap")  which  is $q_n=0$  . you obtain the rod constraint force $~\lambda~$
\begin{align*}
 &\lambda=\left(\frac{1}{2}\frac{h(\varphi~,0)\,D_1(g)(\varphi,0)}{g(\varphi,0)}-
 \,D_1(h)(\varphi,0)+\frac 12 \frac{\partial}{\partial q_n}\,g(\varphi,q_n)\bigg|_{q_n=0}\right)\,\dot{\varphi}^2\\\
 &\text{with}\\
 &D_1(g)(\varphi,0)=\frac{\partial g}{\partial\varphi}\bigg|_{(\varphi,0)}\qquad
 ,D_1(h)(\varphi,0)=\frac{\partial h}{\partial\varphi}\bigg|_{(\varphi,0)}\\
\end{align*}